# Ember controllers in nested routes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm very confuse about how ember controller works.

I'm starting with ember and ember-cli now, and i would like to understand more about how controller works.

If i have an nested route called new, inside a events resource, i should i have:

```
models/event
routes/events/new
templates/events/new
```

What about controllers?? I just work one simple controller, or should i use controllers/events/new too?

There isn't any generator command that will create every resource for me? I need call one by one?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of ember are you using?

Comment: @nem I'm using 1.13.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What about controllers?? I just work one simple controller, or should i use controllers/events/new too?

This mainly depends on what is your controller needs to do. If it's only the essential stuff the controller does anyways, Ember will create that controller under the hood for you and automatically bubble actions up to its parent controller.

No better place than [Ember guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/controllers/) to read what a controller is used for:

The simplest definition is:

> Controllers allow you to decorate your models with display logic.

This means that you basically use them as the main communication layer between your route and your template. Essentially, you model comes from your route, through your controller and into your template. Actions happening in the template go up to the controller and then to the route. Therefore, controller is essentially the middle layer where you user your model (and other data) to *control* what is shown to the user, *control* what a user can do, *control* where can they navigate etc.

---

**However**, be aware of the plan for the future:

> Controllers are very much like components, so much so that in future versions of Ember, controllers will be replaced entirely with components. At the moment, components cannot be routed to, but when this changes, it will be recommended to replace all controllers with components.

This means, that right now, controller responsibility is limited to two things:

1. Maintaining application state based on the current route
2. Handling or bubbling user actions that pass through the controller layer when moving from a component to a route.

All actions triggered on a template are first looked up on the controller, if it is not handled or bubbled (by return true) in the controller, they are looked up on the route.

Therefore, controllers for your `/events` or `events/new` routes aren't necessary at all, only if you want to handle things happening on those routes right away (in a smaller scope) instead of allowing everything to bubble up to the ApplicationController.

---

> There isn't any generator command that will create every resource for me? I need call one by one?

Yes. Since, if you don't specifically create a controller, Ember just generates one for you behind the scenes. You need to specify where you want to handle things yourself.

You should visit the link I gave above (or [here it is again](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/controllers/)) to the Ember guides that have many more examples in much more detail.

Comment: WOW! Great answer @nem, i'm going to read all the guide, i think could help me understand better how ember works. Thanks for the answer and for the tips!!

Comment: @FátimaAlves no problem, glad to help. Ember is awesome, keep learning :)